# Prestashop 1.6: How to get color list for accessories block in product view

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

How can I get color list for each product in accessories block in product view in a loop:

```
{foreach from=$accessories item=accessory name=accessories_list}

{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function `getAttributesColorList` from `Product` class. You need to pass as parameter an array of product IDs. You can call directly in you TPL but I don't recommend it:

```
{foreach from=$accessories item=accessory name=accessories_list}
    {assign var='accesoryColors' value=Product::getAttributesColorList(array($accessory.id_product))}
{/foreach}
```

A cleaner option is to modify $accessories var in controller before pass it to TPL.

Good luck.